# Bindable property change event in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5

Can anyone please help me solve this mystery:

I've got a component called Box.as that has following two properties, and have their getters & setters defined:

```
private var _busy:Boolean;
private var _errorMessage:String;
```

In MXML that uses this component I define it like this:

```
<components:Box skinClass="skins.components.BoxSkin"
                busy="{presenter.boxBusy}"
        errorMessage="{presenter.boxErrorMessage}"/>
```

Where *presenter* variable is defined here in MXML and a Presenter class has boxBusy and boxErrorMessage variables defined as bindable property change events:

```
[Bindable(event="propertyChange")]
function get boxBusy():Boolean;
function set boxBusy(value:Boolean):void;

[Bindable(event="propertyChange")]
function get boxErrorMessage():String;
function set boxErrorMessage(value:String):void;
```

PROBLEM is that whenever I change *boxErrorMessage* for the *presenter*, I see the affect in MXML **but** nothing happens at all when I change *boxBusy*. Is there something extra I need to do with boolean variable?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should omit the `(event="propertyChange")` specification from your `[Bindable]` metadata tags on both `boxBusy` and `boxErrorMessage`.  Also, make sure your get/set methods are declared public.

So, the property, `boxBusy`, would look something like this:

```
[Bindable]
public function get boxBusy():Boolean {  return _busy; }
public function set boxBusy(value:Boolean):void {  _busy = value; }
```

When you qualify `[Bindable]` with `(event="...")`, you're telling Flex, "I will dispatch the named event whenever the binding should be updated".

If you omit the event specification, then flex assumes that the event is named `propertyChange`. But that's not all it does. It also automatically "wraps" your setter with generated code that transparently dispatches a `'propertyChange'` event any time the setter is used to modify the value.  This is described in more detail [here, at adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=databinding_8.html).

So... by explicitly specifying `(event="propertyChange")`, you disable flex's default behavior.  Even though you're using the default event name, flex will not generate the wrapper code -- instead, it will expect you to dispatch the event from your code, at the appropriate time.

I imagine that your `boxErrorMessage` property *appears* to be working, because some other `[Bindable]` property of your class is changing in the same pass -- thus dispatching `propertyChange`, and causing your `boxErrorMessage` binding to update as a side-effect.

Comment: thanks a lot for help @Lee errorMessage property of component box get set every time I change boxErrorMessage. I've confirmed that via debugger as well i.e. if I put 10 lines to update property boxErrorMessage property on every line debugger steps me into Box's setter method for _errorMessage. Appreciate your help matey I'm still pulling my hair... :-(

Comment: getting rid of event="propertyChange" makes boxErrorMessage not to work either.

Comment: @BilalWahla Sorry you're still having trouble with it.  I'm not sure what to tell you at this point though.  If you read the documentation I linked above: it's clear that in the normal case of a simple property, `[Bindable]` --without `(event="...")`-- should be sufficient.  That is also true in all of my experience with flex data binding (which is substantial).  My best advice is to reevaluate your assumptions - something is not what it seems. The real problem is likely elsewhere in your code, or in your build-options.  Good luck.  Sorry I can't offer better advice.

Comment: cheers Lee... You are right, i'm sure it's something small i'm missing somewhere... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible that if you are setting busyBox to **true** the first time the setter is getting called but it will not get called again if you again try to set to **true**.  The code that is by the flex compiler when you use the [Bindable] tag will adds a check to see if you are setting the new value to what the getter will currently will return. If that is the cause it isn't called.
If you were to oscillate between true and false it would get called every time because the new value differs from the current value. But setting it to true-true-true-true-false would only result in it getting called the first time to set to your and the last time to set to false.